# Querying multiple SQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble understanding joins and subqueries and when to use each. I'm sure that one of them is appropriate here.

I have a table ("owners") of (to keep things simple) unit numbers, names and email addresses.

I have another table ("widgets") of unit numbers and the number of widgets assigned to each unit. Each unit has 0, 1 or 2 widgets.

I need to send an email to each unit depending on whether they have 0, 1 or 2 widgets. In other words (and in plain English, not even remotely an attempt at semi-correct SQL):

```
select numwidgets from widgets where unit=x
then where owners.unit = widgets.unit
select unit, name, email
```

The data that I need to pass to my script will look like this:

```
unit     name          email               widgets
1        Bob Smith     bob@example.com     2
```

I can visualise in my mind the data that I need, but it's extracting it from two different tables that is the problem. The "owners" table is a permanent table, and the "widgets" table is a temporary one for tracking a specific issue that is being addressed in the email I'm sending. I don't need help sending the email, just creating the SQL I need to use to extract the data (numwidgets, name, email) for one email.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Input data:

```
owners table:
unit, name, email
1,Bob Smith, bob@example.com

widgets table:
unit,widgets
1,2
```

Comment: Can you post sample input data and expected output in the question?

Comment: @Gurwinder The expected output is above in my original post. I'm not clear on what you mean by "sample input data" if the data above is not the same, just reordered. The expected output ("The data I need to pass to my script") is contained in the database and is the same as the output, just in different tables.

Comment: No, I mean you need the above output built from some input data. Just post that please.

Comment: Added something. Hope it's what you're looking for.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, appreciate the direction. I'll endeavour to provide more and better information in future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, a inner join selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both tables.

Subqueries (also known as inner queries or nested queries) are a tool for performing operations in multiple steps. For example, if you wanted to take the sums of several columns, then average all of those values, you’d need to do each aggregation in a distinct step.

```
select owners.unit, name, email, widgets.numwidgets
from owners
inner join widgets On owners.unit = widgets.unit
where owners.unit = x
```

Comment: Thanks. This works directly on the database -- and so technically answers my question -- but my PHP script is still broken. I'll need to get back this this tomorrow and will close this question then when I figure it all out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select o.*, w.widgets
from owners o
inner join widget w
on o.unit = w.unit
where o.unit = 123;
```

Comment: It's preferable to put conditions on a single table in the `WHERE` clause, `ON` should just be for relationship between tables (except for `OUTER JOIN`).

Comment: Thanks @GurwinderSingh . This is probably the wrong place to ask, but can you explain or suggest reading for the single-letter "o" and "w" syntax? That confused me in other search results I found too. I'm guessing it's related to the first letter of the table names, but what if I have two tables that start with the same letter -- e.g., "owners" and "owners_test", the latter being an abbreviated copy of "owners" with the same structure as but different data.

Comment: It's just an alias for the table. it can be anything...t, x, abcd . It's to facilitate writing bigger join so that you don't have to write `very_very_big_table_name.some_column_name` over and over

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Thanks very much for your explanation. I have upvoted your answer, but because I'm still relatively new my vote apparently counts but doesn't show. I'm going to accept the first answer that came in, but I wish there was a better way to show my appreciation.

Comment: @CraigH I am just glad I helped.

Answer (score 0):

For your case you need an inner join. To understand that you need to see the concept of keys which is pretty simple.
In your tables unitnumber is the common column in both tables. So a join has to be applied based on this column.

Subqueries are used when the output of one query is given as input to another query i.e to perform related operations

Select o.unit,o.name,o.email ,w.numwidgets from owners o inner join widgets w on o.unit=w.unit where w.unit=X

In above query pass X = 0,1,2 as per the result you want

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I'm going to accept the answer that came in first.